# SQL Server Rank() by date, Group and Join two tables including pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, group-by

Having this two tables in SQL Server:

**Shopcart**:

```
id    userid    prodid    qt    date
1     21        P1        1     2017-02-18
2     21        P8        1     2017-02-19
3     21        P2        1     2017-02-20
4     22        P5        1     2017-02-21
5     22        P3        1     2017-02-22
6     23        P4        1     2017-02-23
```

**Users**:

```
id    user_name
21    John
22    James
23    Alice
24    Lily
```

I want a table where are shown only **articles** with newest date, grouped by user_id,having 1 column (art_c) with count of articles that each user added to shopcart (not Qt, that is quantity), and joined with table of **Users**.
Also, i want to add pagination for each row of result.

**Result I want is like this:**

```
id    userid    user_name    prodid   art_c   date
3     21        John         P2       3       2017-02-20
5     22        James        P3       2       2017-02-22
6     23        Alice        P4       1       2017-02-23
```

What is the best/fastest aproach to do so?
I'm using this request, and I'm not sure if it is good/fast way to go:

```
With tb_a as 
(
  SELECT u_id,u_name,dat,art_c,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY u_name) as rgw FROM
  shopcart a
  LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT 
       a.userid as u_id,
       b.user_name as u_name,
       Format(shop_date, 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm') as dat,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.userid ORDER BY shop_date DESC) as dest_rank,
       Count(a.id) OVER (PARTITION BY a.userid ORDER BY shop_date) as art_c
       FROM 
            shopcart a
       LEFT JOIN 
            Users b on a.userid=b.id
  group by 
       a.userid,b.name,shop_date,a.id) b on a.userid=b.u_id 
  where dest_rank = 1
  group by u_id,u_name,dat,art_c
)

SELECT * FROM tb_a
WHERE rgw BETWEEN 0 AND 100 order by rgw
```

Comment: If you are concerned about speed, suggest not using `FORMAT()` https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Comment: What to do when there are two products with the same newest date for a user?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This is just example, in DB I have datetime that has precision to miliseconds

Comment: @mendosi Thanks, I didn't knew about `FORMAT()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to use `row_number()` on `ShopCart`.  I would do it before the `join`:

```
select u.*, sc.*
from (select sc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sc.userid order by date desc) as seqnum
      from ShopCart sc
     ) sc join
     users u
     on sc.userid = u.id
where seqnum = 1;
```

For pagination, you would add `order by` and you can then use `offset` and `fetch next`.

EDIT:

You can get the count as well, using window functions:

```
select u.*, sc.*
from (select sc.*,
             row_number() over (partition by sc.userid order by date desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by sc.userid) as cnt
      from ShopCart sc
     ) sc join
     users u
     on sc.userid = u.id
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you think, `offset` and `fetch next` will work faster or slower than aproach with `ROW_NUMBER()` ?

Comment: @MaxWater . . . I would use `OFFSET` and `FETCH NEXT`.  They were designed for pagination.

Comment: it's a magic! Thank you! This method of pagination is also awesome. Strange, but I didn't knew about it. It's much simplier to write `OFFSET` and `FETCH` than use `WITH` clause and stuff. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use with statement and **Row_Number** as below, **PartNo** column will group your data by userId and **SeqNo** column get user wise count:

```
;WITH S AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        COUNT(Id) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId) AS PartNo,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId Order BY Date DESC) AS SeqNo
    FROM @ShopCart SC
)

SELECT
    S.Id,
    S.UserId,
    U.UserName  ,
    S.ProdId,
    S.PartNo AS Art_c,
    S.Date
FROM S
LEFT JOIN @User U ON S.UserId=U.Id
WHERE S.SeqNo=1
```

Comment: Very nice and clean solution. (You can replace `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserId Order BY Date)` with `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId)` if you find this more readable, though.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner This solution and yours are working and giving results I want, but execution plans are different. I don't know which is better

Comment: I don't know either, but it's likely that Gordon's and Sandip's queries are faster than mine. They read the table just once.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH Shopcart (id,userid,prodid,qt,date)
As
(
Select 1, 21,'P1',1, '2017-02-18' Union all
Select 2, 21,'P8',1, '2017-02-19' Union all
Select 3, 21,'P2',1, '2017-02-20' Union all
Select 4, 22,'P5',1, '2017-02-21' Union all
Select 5, 22,'P3',1, '2017-02-22' Union all
Select 6, 23,'P4',1, '2017-02-23'
)
,Users(id,[user_name])
As
(
Select 21,'John'  Union all
Select 22,'James' Union all
Select 23,'Alice' Union all
Select 24,'Lily'
)

,cte_result AS (
        SELECT c.id
            ,c.userid
            ,u.[user_name]
            ,c.prodid
            ,c.[date]
            ,COUNT(qt) OVER (PARTITION BY userid,[user_name]) art_c
            ,Row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY [user_name] ORDER BY [user_name],[date] DESC   ) Seq
        FROM Shopcart c
        INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id = c.userid
        )


SELECT id
    ,userid
    ,[user_name]
    ,prodid
    ,art_c
    ,[date]
FROM cte_result
WHERE Seq = 1
ORDER BY 1
```